# How to retrieve values from multiple columns in sql tables when Image click on ListView of vb.net form?

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview

your valuable suggestions are highly appreciated.

I created sql table as follows.

```
Create table Products (
ItemCode int NOT NUll Primary Key,
ItemName varchar(255),
ItemImage varbinary(MAX),
Category int,
Price Money,
Note varchar(255))
```

Then I created a vb.net windows form which contains some textboxes and Listview. and gave following code at form load event.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports System.IO

Public Class items
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myPosConString").ConnectionString)
    Dim Command As SqlCommand
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Query As String


    'Fill Items with pictures into listview
    Private Sub FillItemListView()
        Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt_Images As New DataTable

        Try
            lvItem.Clear()
            Dim imglist As New ImageList
            imglist.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
            lvItem.LargeImageList = imglist
            lvItem.LargeImageList.ImageSize = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
            sqlCon.Open()
            Query = "select * from products "
            Command = New SqlCommand(Query, sqlCon)
            Adapter.SelectCommand = Command
            Adapter.Fill(dt_Images)

            For Each dr As DataRow In dt_Images.Rows

                Dim img_buffer = CType(dr("ItemImage"), Byte())
                Dim img_stream As New MemoryStream(img_buffer, True)
                img_stream.Write(img_buffer, 0, img_buffer.Length)
                imglist.Images.Add(dr("ItemCode").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
                img_stream.Close()
                Dim lstv As New ListViewItem
                lstv.Text = dr("ItemName").ToString
                lstv.ImageKey = dr("ItemCode").ToString
                lvItem.Items.Add(lstv)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub items_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillItemListView()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Everything is working as I wanted. But I want all my textboxes to get values from other columns of sql table when I click on a large image in Listview.

listview name is `lvItem` and 
txtboxes are `txtCode`, `txtName`, `txtCategory`, `txtPrice`, `txtNote`.

Can you please teach me how to do this. 
thank you.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of code and agony if you used a DataTable and DataGridView -  `myDGV.DataSource = myDataTable` would replace all that code to copy strings to a LV

Comment: thanks @Plutonix , but can I have images from sql table as icons horizontally in DataGridView ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a `View` other than `Details` in the `ListView` then a `ListView` it must be, as the `DataGridView` doesn't support the other views.

I would suggest that you bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to your `TextBoxes`.  When the user selects an item in the `ListView`, you can assign the `Index` of that item to the `Position` of the `BindingSource`.  That will then display the fields of the row at that index in the bound `TextBoxes`.

If the user can sort your `ListView` then you could also set the `Sort` property of the `BindingSource` to keep them in sync.